# For what real values of $k$ does the series $\sum\frac{k^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I think it's $|k| < 1$, but I don't know how to prove it. It's either that or it never converges. $\sum\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ obviously diverges, but can't an exponential beat it and make the sum finite?

Comment: What about $k=-1$?

Comment: Just as a side note, it can be proved with a little more effort (using Cauchy root test and generalized alternate test) that if $k \in \mathbb{C}$ the series converges for all $|k| \leq 1$ and $k \neq 1$

Comment: Look for "radius of convergence" in your calculus textbook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do [D'alembert's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) you will have 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}{\left|\frac{\frac{k^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}}{\frac{k^n}{\sqrt{n}}}\right|}
= \lim_{n \to \infty}{\left|\frac{k^{n+1}\sqrt{n}}{k^n\sqrt{n+1}}\right|}
= \lim_{n \to \infty}{|k|\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}} = |k|
$$
So this tells you that the series converges for $|k| < 1$ and diverges for $|k| > 1$, for $k = 1$ it diverges like you said, and for $k = -1$ it is easy to see using [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) that the series converges.

Comment: I think the Alternate series test is easier for $k=-1$ ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_test ).

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. I would recommend using a comparison test to the geometric series $\sum k^n$ to show convergence and comparison to the series $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $ to show divergence.

Comment: @Luke: I note that you should consider the endpoints, when k = 1 and -1, separately.